# How do I compress multiple for statements so the user can change the number of them

Tags: python

I have a code that is getting every combination of numbers (1 to 4) that adding them up will get you the number you inserted (n in this case)...

It's basically listing every combination of numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 in n digits with added if statements for excluding the ones I need in another programme.

The way I have it setup now is that its locked to 6 digits because I have to manually change the number of for statements for that to change. My question is how do I make it so I can have as many for statements as I enter in the console.

Here is my code:

```
def num_of_comb(n):
    counter = 0
    for a in range(1, 5):
        if a == n:
            print(str(a))
            counter += 1
        for b in range(1, 5):
            if a+b == n:
                print(str(a) + str(b))
                counter += 1
            for c in range(1, 5):
                if a+b+c == n:
                    print(str(a) + str(b) + str(c))
                    counter += 1
                for d in range(1, 5):
                    if a+b+c+d == n:
                        print(str(a) + str(b) + str(c) + str(d))
                        counter += 1
                    for e in range(1, 5):
                        if a+b+c+d+e == n:
                            print(str(a) + str(b) + str(c) + str(d) + str(e))
                            counter += 1
                        for f in range(1, 5):
                            if a+b+c+d+e+f == n:
                                print(str(a) + str(b) + str(c) + str(d) + str(e) + str(f))
                                counter += 1

    return counter

print(num_of_comb(int(input("Unesi broj: "))))
```

The outcome of this code will only be correct if I enter 6, because there are 6 for statements.

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations()`.

Comment: For the specific purpose of "compressing for loops" I would go with `itertools.product` and `xrange` which does exactly that

Comment: @CorentinPane that worked, thank you... I tried ```itertools.combinations()``` first but all I got was an empty string, product() worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `itertools.product` to replace nested `for` loops.

```py
from itertools import product
numberOfLoops = int(input("Number of loops?"))

for t in product(range(1, 5), repeat=numberOfLoops):
    # t is a tuple with all loops variables in it
    if sum(t) == n:
        # do stuff
```

You can read the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Note that for the specific purpose you're trying to achieve, there might be other interesting options like `itertools.combinations`.